# Putty + Bash + Screen, up arrow for history not working (Ubuntu 11.10)

Tags: ubuntu, bash, troubleshooting, gnu-screen, putty

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu Server 11.10 that I am logging into SSH via PuTTy.  When I am inside screen, I cannot use the up arrow to recall bash history (though this works outside of screen).  I cannot seem to find the exact same problem on the Interwebs (though many similar ones).  My .screenrc is below:

```
# Look and feel
caption always "%{= bb}%{+b w}Screen: %n | %h %=%t %c"
hardstatus alwayslastline "%-Lw%{= BW}%50>%n%f* %t%{-}%+Lw%<"

# Our warning of activity
activity "Activity in %t(%n)"

# Left Right meta key mods
#ALT-,. and ALT-<>
bindkey "^[<" eval number !echo $WINDOW-1|bc
bindkey "^[>" eval number !echo $WINDOW+1|bc
bindkey "^[," prev
bindkey "^[." next

#disable startup banner
startup_message off

#see http://www4.informatik.uni-erlangen.de/~jnweiger/screen-faq.html
termcap  xterm 'XT:AF=\E[3%dm:AB=\E[4%dm:AX'
terminfo xterm 'XT:AF=\E[3%p1%dm:AB=\E[4%p1%dm:AX'
termcapinfo xterm 'XT:AF=\E[3%p1%dm:AB=\E[4%p1%dm:AX:hs:ts=\E]2;:fs=\007:ds=\E]2;screen\007'
termcap  xtermc 'XT:AF=\E[3%dm:AB=\E[4%dm:AX'
terminfo xtermc 'XT:AF=\E[3%p1%dm:AB=\E[4%p1%dm:AX'
termcapinfo xtermc 'XT:AF=\E[3%p1%dm:AB=\E[4%p1%dm:AX:hs:ts=\E]2;:fs=\007:ds=\E]2;screen\007'

#scrollback
termcapinfo xterm ti@:te@

shell -$SHELL
```

UPDATE:
The up arrow works properly in other apps such as vim and less.  This problem occurs on the physical console as well as in PuTTy.

Comment: When in screen what is the value of the $TERM variable?

Comment: "screen".  I have tried changing it to "vt100" with no change in behavior.

Comment: The default terminal type in Putty is "xterm" have you tried using that setting?

Comment: Good point, however I do not think Putty is the issue for two reasons: 1.) Other Ubuntu (10.04LTS) servers' screen+bash work fine with the default PuTTy config, 2.) This issue crops up even when logged into the physical console.

Comment: I have the same problem too on all my CentOS system. I want to know the answer too. :)

Comment: Added mystery: This issue is on one of my local VMs.  I installed another VM on our cluster with the same install ISO and same .screenrc, and bash history works as expected with the up arrow.  Now I am really scratching my head!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem.  Turns out the user account I created didn't have a default shell set.

Comment: /bin/bash is default in passwd and $SHELL

Comment: I had the same problem with a new debian server, and this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd> to enter copy/scrollback mode and then navigate using <kbd>h</kbd> <kbd>j</kbd> <kbd>k</kbd> <kbd>l</kbd> or arrow keys.

Read this for navigation options - http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/screen_11.html